# Urlopen in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler, urlopen

I am playing around trying to extract some info from a webpage and I have the following code:

```
import re
from math import ceil
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

InitUrl="https://mtgsingles.gr/search?q="
NumOfCrawledPages = 0
URL_Next = ""
NumOfPages=5

for i in range(0, NumOfPages):
    if i == 0:
        Url = InitUrl
    else:
        Url = URL_Next

    UClient = uReq(Url)  # downloading the url
    page_html = UClient.read()
    UClient.close()

    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")


    cards = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": ["iso-item", "item-row-view"]})


    for card in cards:
        card_name = card.div.div.strong.span.contents[3].contents[0].replace("\xa0 ", "")

        if len(card.div.contents) > 3:
            cardP_T = card.div.contents[3].contents[1].text.replace("\n", "").strip()
        else:
            cardP_T = "Does not exist"

        cardType = card.contents[3].text
        print(card_name + "\n" + cardP_T + "\n" + cardType + "\n")


    try:
        URL_Next = "https://mtgsingles.gr" + page_soup.findAll("li", {"class": "next"})[0].contents[0].get("href")
        print("The next URL is: " + URL_Next + "\n")
    except IndexError:
        print("Crawling process completed! No more infomation to retrieve!")
    else:
        print("The next URL is: " + URL_Next + "\n")
        NumOfCrawledPages += 1
        Url= URL_Next

    finally:
        print("Moving to page : " + str(NumOfCrawledPages + 1) + "\n")
```

The code runs fine and no errors occur but the results are not as expected. I am trying to extract some information from the page as well as the url of the next page. Ultimately I would like the program to run 5 times and crawl 5 pages. But this code crawls the initial page given (InitUrl="xyz.com") all 5 times and does not proceed in the next page url that is extracted.
I tried debugging it by entering some print statements to see where the problem lies and I think that the problem lies at these statements:

```
 UClient = uReq(Url) 
 page_html = UClient.read()
 UClient.close()
```

For some reason urlopen does not work repeatedly in the for loop.
Why does this happen?

Comment: **@Petris**, please check the variable names, e.g. **InitURL** and **InitUrl** and retry. If it's ok for you to share the original website's link then it would be better for us to figure out the problem, in case if you still have the issue.

Comment: The issue is probably your last else-clause. It has no if. So that block throws an error which means Url is never set besides the value it already has...

Comment: I checked the variable names and they are ok! I just mispelled them when i asked the question here. The website is https://mtgsingles.gr/search?q=